# Writing a custom JSF Tag

Tags: jsf, jsp-tags

I am trying to write a custom tag.  I can write attributes; however, I'm having difficulty writing the innerHTML part:

```
<span class="required">*</span>
```

I can write:

```
writer.startElement("span", component);
writer.writeAttribute("class", "required", "class");
writer.endElement("span");
```

How do I write the *?

http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriter.html

This is a simple example, essentially, I would like to wrap some other JSF components to simplify what goes into my xhtml file.

Thanks,
Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by *digitalross*, you can simply write text:

```
writer.startElement("span", component);
writer.writeAttribute("class", "required", "class");
writer.writeText("*");
writer.endElement("span");
```

If you need to include another HTML tags (instead of text):

```
writer.startElement("span", component);
writer.writeAttribute("class", "required", "class");
writer.startElement("xxx", component);
...
writer.endElement("xxx");
writer.endElement("span");
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that what [ResponseWriter.writeText](http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriter.html) does?